# Duplicate NSLog entries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nslog, awakefromnib

I don't know if it's possible for me to include code here that's relevant as my project is so large but are there any typical reasons why `NSLog` would repeat some warnings and calls to it at occasions where only one call/error is occuring?

As an example, I have a subclass of `NSBox` that inits an instance of another class on `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    burbControllerInstance = [[BurbController alloc] init];
    if (burbControllerInstance) {
        NSLog(@"init ok");
    }
}
```

I get `NSLog` printing "init ok" twice. I don't see why this subclass would be 'awoken' twice anywhere in my project. This is part of a larger problem where I can't get variables to return anything but `nil` from the class I'm creating an instance of. I'm wondering if perhaps the double values are something to do with it.

Comment: Are you deriving from that class?

Comment: Define deriving. As in, retrieving variables? No, I am calling a method in the BurbController class that alters a bunch of variables only relevant to that class. They hold correct data when the method is run inside its own class but hold 'nil' when I call the method from my NSBox subclass.

Comment: No, I don't believe I am. I've subclassed `NSbox` for only one object in my interface and I've only overruled methods relating to printing and pagination for `NSBox` in this one object. I don't see where else it would be awoken twice on the application starting up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/26/cocoa-tutorial-awakefromnib-vs-applicationdidfinishlaunching/) could be helpful, i. e. one comment:

> Also important: awakeFromNib can be
>   called multiple times on the
>   controller if you use the same
>   controller for several nibs – say,
>   you’re using the app delegate as the
>   owner of both the app’s About Box and
>   preferences dialog. So you’ll need an
>   extra guard test if you use
>   awakeFromNib for anything but
>   initializing the nib objects

**Update:** Much more interesting could also be [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/71651-double-call-of-awakefromnib-on-custom-view.html), where the author mentions that `awakeFromNib` gets called **twice**. Unfortunately there is no real answer for this particular problem but maybe some basic ideas.

**Update #2:** Another potential solution from stackoverflow.com: [View Controller calls awakeFromNib twice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152876/view-controller-calls-awakefromnib-twice)

Comment: Aha, the last link helped a lot. It gave the idea that I didn't need to initialise my subclass through the nib palette, as I usually do. So what was happening was the nib was being started by my object in my interface and also in the nib palette. It was a bad habit I'd picked up. Thankyou! Now onto figuring out why my variables still don't return values....

Comment: @biscuitstack: Ok, that was also the intention when i was asking about deriving from that class. Usual in this case multiple objects were initialized.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks, I'm still not at this that long so sometimes only catch onto things when they're spelt out a little more specifically.

Comment: No problem, especially large projects are sometimes somewhat difficult.